# Post DB migrate validation

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-migration

We have migrated our on-premises SQL DB to Azure. How do we perform the post migration validation of the databases to confirm if the schema, size of db, users etc.. in Azure are matching with the source db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Data Migration Assistant (DMA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-2017).

The Data Migration Assistant (DMA) helps you upgrade to a modern data platform by detecting compatibility issues that can impact database functionality in your new version of SQL Server or Azure SQL Database. DMA recommends performance and reliability improvements for your target environment and allows you to move your schema, data, and uncontained objects from your source server to your target server.

Assess on-premises SQL Server instance(s) migrating to Azure SQL database(s). The assessment workflow helps you to detect the following issues that can affect Azure SQL database migration and provides detailed guidance on how to resolve them.

1. Migration blocking issues: Discovers the compatibility issues that block migrating on-premises SQL Server database(s) to Azure SQL Database(s). DMA provides recommendations to help you address those issues.
2. Partially supported or unsupported features: Detects partially supported or unsupported features that are currently in use on the source SQL Server instance. DMA provides a comprehensive set of recommendations, alternative approaches available in Azure, and mitigating steps so that you can incorporate them into your migration projects.

Since you have migrated your on-premises SQL DB to Azure, you also can use DMA to  get the [assess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-assesssqlonprem?view=sql-server-2017) report. It will help you know if the schema, size of db, users etc.. in Azure are matching with the source db.

If you still not sure, you can run the same queries in your on-premises DB and Azure SQL database, compare the results.Such as:

List Schema:

```
select s.name as schema_name,
    s.schema_id,
    u.name as schema_owner
from sys.schemas s
    inner join sys.sysusers u
        on u.uid = s.principal_id
order by s.name
```

Hope this helps.